# Conditional Formatting applied to column based on changing custom formula not working

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, match, conditional-formatting

I am decent with excel/google sheets but haven't had any formal education with it so everything I know I have learned from the internet. With that said.

I am working on a spreadsheet that already has multiple conditional formatting rules across the entire spreadsheet. They all are working as I want except for this one I have applied:

In Column C, I want the cell to highlight if column L is greater than column K. Here is the formula example I am currently using: Apply to C65, custom formula L65>K65

The cells aren't highlighting as they should. If it makes a difference this is with Google sheets.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: If you  have a new question, post a new post instead. Ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the CF rule should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I realized I was missing the equal sign like right after posting. With the second part to my question, I tried the C65:C (actually C2:C since it is for the entire column) and it highlights a bunch of random cells. For example, in the range C41:C61 only one cell C57 should be highlighted but instead about half of them are

Comment: @Emma looks like you have a formatting issue. try like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SmDZ.png